# filter a listview populated from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview

i added a filter to my listview ( populated from sqlite ). i am using this method to fetch the records from sqlite

```
 public Cursor fetchServicesByName(String inputText, String c) throws SQLException {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      Cursor mCursor = null;
      if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
       mCursor = db.query(TABLE_SERVICE, new String[] {KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,
         KEY_ADRESSE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_NUMTEL, KEY_WEBSITE,KEY_IMAGE}, KEY_TYPE + "=?",
         new String[] { c },null, null, null, null);

      }
      else {
       mCursor = db.query(true, TABLE_SERVICE, new String[] {KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,
               KEY_ADRESSE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_NUMTEL, KEY_WEBSITE,KEY_IMAGE},
         KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'" , null,
         null, null, null, null);
      }
      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;
```

this is working, but what i want to do is to filter by inputText and KEY_TYPE

i used this (instead of the last db.query ) but it didn't return anything

```
 mCursor = db.query(TABLE_SERVICE, new String[] {KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,
               KEY_ADRESSE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_NUMTEL, KEY_WEBSITE,KEY_IMAGE},
         KEY_NAME + " like ? and" + KEY_TYPE + " like ? " , new String[] { inputText, c},
         null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: This might be that you forgot a space as *" LIKE ? AND "*, after *"and"*.. I'm not sure about that, but I don't see anything else. Let me know if your query method works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your inputtext and keytype are null!
Aris your routine working when you fill out your inputtext and c vallue?

Comment: no, it hadn't worked
when i added this KEY_NAME + " like ? and" + KEY_TYPE + " like ? "